# How to include Google App Engine Endpoints in a Cordova project?

Tags: android, cordova, google-app-engine, endpoints

Hello All i am new into Cordova, Right now i have developed a web application using Google datastore, but now i want to use the same endpoints library into my cordova project. I have generated my Endpoints SNAPSHOT.jar file, how do i proceed from here on? Please help me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Endpoints makes it easier to create a web backend for **web clients** and
>   mobile clients such as Android or Apple's iOS.

Since Cordova uses JavaScript mostly and can essentially act as a web client, you can use the [**Endpoint's JavaScript Client library**](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/consume_js) to simply make direct API calls to your endpoints from your app without the need to add the `.jar` file.

Comment: Google has deprecated its v1 Endpoints library. You should use the new Google JavaScript client library instead. You can find more informatión here: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/consume_js